# Checksum and Bitshift

Tags: c++, checksum

I'm learning to create a raw packet and send it following [this](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~steflik/cs455/rawip.txt) tutorial. Everything makes sense until i reach the code where the checksum is generated.

```
unsigned short csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{
  unsigned long sum;
  for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
    sum += *buf++;
  sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
  sum += (sum >> 16);
  return ~sum;
}
```

It looks like that he's summing up all the words in the buffer. but when I hit

```
  sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
  sum += (sum >> 16);
```

I get completely lost. Looks like he shifts all the bits right, essentially discarding all the bits except the carry over and then adding it back into the original sum? Why is the & 0xfff necessary? after all that, why does the add the carry out bits again? is it because there might be a second carry out?

Comment: brain's stopped working apparently (X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
```

Adds the left and right 16-bit words in the 32-bit integer.  It basically splits the number in half and adds the two halves together.  sum>>16 gives you the left half, and sum & 0xffff gives you the right half.

Then when these 2 are added together, they could possible overflow.   This line:

```
sum += (sum >> 16);
```

Adds the overflow back into the original number.

Answer (score 0):

The checksum being computed is 16-bit (`unsigned short` is very often 16-bit), but the variable `sum` is `unsigned long`, and thus probably 32 bit.

So the operation `sum >> 16` captures the high word of the sum, all the times that pairs of words have summed to more than 16 bit can hold. This is then mixed with `sum & 0xffff` which is just the low word of the sum.

This way, all bits of the sum are "folded in" so that they contribute to the final result.